# Why when I run my Mockito test I get Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have Service class That uses Dao class. I use javax Inject Annotation.

Service class:

```
 public class TaxiServiceCar {
        @Inject
        private final CarDao carDao;
        public TaxiServiceCar(CarDao carDao){
            this.carDao = carDao;
        }
        public boolean insertCar(Car car) {
            Connection connection = MySQLDAOFactory.getConnection();
            boolean result =  carDao.insertCar(connection,car);
            ConnectionUtil.commit(connection);
            ConnectionUtil.oneMethodToCloseThemAll(null,null,connection);
            return result;
        }
// Others methods
}
```

I have ServiceTest Class where I use mockito

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TaxiServiceCarTest {
    @Mock
    private CarDao carDao;
    @InjectMocks
    private TaxiServiceCar taxiServiceCar;
    @Test
    void insertCar() {
        when(carDao.insertCar(any(Connection.class),any(Car.class))).thenReturn(true);
        Car car = new Car();
        assertTrue(taxiServiceCar.insertCar(car));
    }
//others Test methods
}
```

When I run test I get NullPointer Exception In MySQLDAOFactory class where I obtain connection from Connection pool
Where I get NPE

```
public class MySQLDAOFactory extends DAOFactory {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MySQLDAOFactory.class);//Here
    private static DataSource dataSource;

    public static void dataSourceInit(){
        try {
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
            dataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/UsersDB");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }
    }
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if(dataSource==null){
            dataSourceInit();
        }
       Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();//Here
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }
        return connection;
    }
    @Override
    public CarDao getCarDao() {
        return new MySQLCarDao();
    }
    @Override
    public UserDao getUserDao() {
        return new MySQLUserDao();
    }
    @Override
    public OrderDao getOrderDao() {
        return new MySQLOrderDao();
    }
    @Override
    public CarCategoryDao getCarCategoryDao() {
        return new MySQLCarCategoryDao();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
[Error What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R4ox.png)

And I get NPE also when I'm trying to get Logger in MySQLDAOFactory

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MySQLDAOFactory.class);
```

[Logger error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7npkb.png)

```
2021-06-02 23:56:50,293 main DEBUG Apache Log4j Core 2.14.1 initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=D:\Projects\Epam\FinalProjectException\target\classes\log4j2.xml]
2021-06-02 23:56:50,303 main DEBUG Installed 1 script engine
2021-06-02 23:56:50,512 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn version: 1.8.0_281, language: ECMAScript, threading: Not Thread Safe, compile: true, names: [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript], factory class: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
2021-06-02 23:56:50,513 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 122 plugins
2021-06-02 23:56:50,513 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2021-06-02 23:56:50,516 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
2021-06-02 23:56:50,518 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2021-06-02 23:56:50,524 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
2021-06-02 23:56:50,533 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} %p   %c{1}   %M   - - - - - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(D:\Projects\Epam\FinalProjectException\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2021-06-02 23:56:50,534 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 44 plugins
2021-06-02 23:56:50,545 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy].
2021-06-02 23:56:50,550 main DEBUG createPolicy(size="5MB")
2021-06-02 23:56:50,551 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy].
2021-06-02 23:56:50,552 main DEBUG createPolicy(={SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=5242880)})
2021-06-02 23:56:50,552 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=DefaultRolloverStrategy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy].
2021-06-02 23:56:50,555 main DEBUG DefaultRolloverStrategy$Builder(max="10", min="null", fileIndex="null", compressionLevel="null", ={}, stopCustomActionsOnError="null", tempCompressedFilePattern="null", Configuration(D:\Projects\Epam\FinalProjectException\target\classes\log4j2.xml))
2021-06-02 23:56:50,556 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender].
2021-06-02 23:56:50,561 main DEBUG RollingFileAppender$Builder(fileName="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/log.log", filePattern="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/log%i.log", append="true", locking="null", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=5242880)])), DefaultRolloverStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=10, useMax=true)), advertise="null", advertiseUri="null", createOnDemand="null", filePermissions="null", fileOwner="null", fileGroup="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="true", ignoreExceptions="false", PatternLayout(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} %p   %c{1}   %M   - - - - - %m%n), name="rollingFile", Configuration(D:\Projects\Epam\FinalProjectException\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null, ={})
2021-06-02 23:56:50,565 main ERROR Unable to create file ${sys:catalina.home}/logs/log.log java.io.IOException: Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:720)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:704)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1000)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:940)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:932)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:551)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:241)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:287)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:627)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:700)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:717)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:272)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.mysql.MySQLDAOFactory.<clinit>(MySQLDAOFactory.java:16)
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.services.TaxiServiceCar.insertCar(TaxiServiceCar.java:20)
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.services.TaxiServiceCarTest.insertCar(TaxiServiceCarTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)

2021-06-02 23:56:50,567 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@76c7beb3] unable to create manager for [${sys:catalina.home}/logs/log.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@64337702[pattern=${sys:catalina.home}/logs/log%i.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=5242880)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=10, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} %p   %c{1}   %M   - - - - - %m%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@76c7beb3] unable to create manager for [${sys:catalina.home}/logs/log.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@64337702[pattern=${sys:catalina.home}/logs/log%i.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=5242880)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=10, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} %p   %c{1}   %M   - - - - - %m%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1000)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:940)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:932)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:551)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:241)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:287)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:627)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:700)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:717)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:272)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.mysql.MySQLDAOFactory.<clinit>(MySQLDAOFactory.java:16)
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.services.TaxiServiceCar.insertCar(TaxiServiceCar.java:20)
    at com.example.FinalProjectPM.db.services.TaxiServiceCarTest.insertCar(TaxiServiceCarTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Note that if you're using constructor injection (which is good and the best way to do things) you need to put `@Inject` on the constructor instead of on the field. You're also getting much more detail than just "an NPE", and you need to include it.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I edited post

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Do I need to post more information?

Comment: You need to post your stack trace (1) as text, not an image (2) inline in your question rather than as a link.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I added StackTrace

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Do you know how to solve that problem?